# About Recursion for Newbies in Java

Tags: java, recursion, return, static-methods

So, I have this code, which is just the way I solved an exercise that was given to me, which consisted of creating a recursive function that received a number, and then gave you the sum of 1, all the numbers in between, and your number. I know I made it sound confusing, but here's an example:

If I inserted the number 5, then the returned value would have to be 15, because: 1+2+3+4+5 = 15.

```
public class Exercise {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int returnedValue = addNumbers(6);
        System.out.print(returnedValue);
    }

    public static int addNumbers(int value) {
        if (value == 1) return value;
        return value = value + addNumbers(value-1);
    }

}
```

Technically speaking, my code works just fine, but I still don't get why Eclipse made me write two returns, that's all I would like to know.

Is there a way I could only write "return" once?

Comment: *Eclipse made me write two returns*: what does that mean? What did Eclipse say, precisely? About what code? What's wrong with the above code and why do you think you should have only one return? What would the code look like? Why don't you simply use `return value + addNumbers(value-1);` instead of `return value = value + addNumbers(value-1);`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, you can write it with just one return:

```
public static int addNumbers(int value) {
   if (value > 1) {
      value += addNumbers(value - 1);
   }
   return value;
}
```

As you can see, it's done by having some variable retain the running result until you get to the end.  In this case I was able to do it in-place in `value`, in other cases you may need to create a local variable, but the idea of storing your intermediate result somewhere until you get to the return point is a general one.

Comment: This is the absolute most readable and sensible answer this question could have.

Comment: The explanation below was awesome too, but yours is so straight to the point I couldn't not mark it as the correct answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There should be two returns. Your first return says

```
if at 1: stop recurstion
```

and the second one says

```
continue recursion by returning my value plus computing the value less than me
```

You could combine them by using a ternary:

```
return value == 1 ? value : value + addNumbers(value - 1)
```

But it is not as readable.

Recursive funtions like

- Fibbonacci's sequence
- Fractals
- Etc.

Use themselves multiple times because they *contain* themselves.

Answer (score 1):

Recursive functions always have at least 2 paths, the normal ones that will recurse and the "end" paths that just return (Usually a constant).

You could, however, do something like this:

```
public static int addNumbers(int value) {
    if (value != 1) 
        value = value + addNumbers(value-1);
    return value;
}
```

But I can't say I think it's much better (Some people get as annoyed at modifying parameters as they do at multiple returns).  You could, of course, create a new variable and set it to one value or the other, but then someone would get upset because you used too many lines of code and an unnecessary variable.  Welcome to programming :)  Your original code is probably as good as you're likely to get.

As for why "Eclipse" did that to you, it's actually Java--Java is better than most languages at making sure you didn't do something clearly wrong as soon as possible (In this case while you are typing instead of waiting for you to compile).  It detected that one branch of your if returned a value and the other did not--which is clearly wrong.

Java is also very explicit forcing you to use a "return" statement where another language might let you get away with less.  In Groovy You'd be tempted to eliminate the return and write something like:

```
def addNumbers(value){value + (value-1?0:addNumbers(value-1))}
```

just for fun but I certainly wouldn't call THAT more readable!  Java just figures it's better to force you to be explicit in most cases.

Comment: I recommend `> 1` rather than `!= 1`, lest the user enters a 0 or negative number...

Comment: @Pjs I actually though of the < thing while I was writing, but in terms of how I learned in Basic without integer variables so long ago and sometimes 1 just magically became .999999 and no longer =1.  Good points but I was trying to stay as close to the original question as I could, so I'll go fix the paths but might leave the =1 for now.

Answer (score 1):

Feel free to correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't think there is a way to eliminate one of those returns unless you decide to put a variable outside of the method or change the method from being recursive.

In java, a method that returns a value, MUST return a value at some point, no matter what code inside of it does. The reason eclipse requires you to add the second return, is because the first return is only run if your if statement evaluates to true. If you didn't have the second return, and that if statement did not end up being true, java would not be able to leave that method, and would have no idea what to do, thus, eclipse will require you to add a return statement after that if statement.

These types of errors are called checked errors or compile time errors. This means that eclipse literally can not convert your code into a runnable file, because it does not know how; there is a syntax error, or you are missing a return, etc.

Comment: I'd say you're pretty clearly wrong.  See counterexamples in other answers.

Comment: As pjs pointed out in his/her own answer, you can write it with just one return.

Comment: @pjs Yeah... Didn't think of that.

Answer (score 0):

From the wikipedia on recursion:

> In mathematics and computer science, a class of objects or methods
>   exhibit recursive behavior when they can be defined by two properties:
>
> 1. A simple base case (or cases)—a terminating scenario that does not use recursion to produce an answer
> 2. A set of rules that reduce all other cases toward the base case

There are two returns because you have to handle the two cases above. In your example:

The base case is `value == 1`.

The case to reduce all other cases toward the base case is `value + addNumbers(value-1);`.

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion#Formal_definitions

Of course there are other ways to write this, including some that do not require multiple returns, but in general multiple returns are a clear and normal way to express recursion because of the way recursion naturally falls into multiple cases.

Answer (score 0):

Like the robots of Asimov, all recursive algorithms must obey three important laws:

1. A recursive algorithm must have a base case.
2. A recursive algorithm must change its state and move toward the base case.
3. A recursive algorithm must call itself, recursively.

Your `if (value == 1) return value;` return statement is the **base case**. That's when the recursion(calling itself) stops. When a function call happen, the compiler pushes the current state to stack then make the call. So, when that call has returned some value, it pulls the value from stack, makes calculation and return the result to upper level. That's why the other return statement is for.

Think of this like breaking up your problem:

```
addNumbers(3) = 3 + addNumbers(2) (this is returned by second one)
                      -> 2 + addNumbers(1) (this is returned by second one)
                               -> 1 (this is returned by base case)
```